# Simple C# foreach to LINQ question

Tags: c#, linq

Currently have this:

```
foreach (var series in Chart1.Series)
{
    series.Enabled = false;
}
```

I would like to express this in a simple, one line expression. I thought this would work:

```
Chart1.Series.Select( series => series.Enabled = false);
```

This doesn't have any effect, however. Presumably because I just misunderstood how Select was working, which is fine.

My next thought was to do something like Chart1.Series.ForEach( series => series.Enabled = false), but Chart1.Series does not implement IEnumberable (..or at least ForEach is not an acceptable method to call).

I'd rather not do `Chart1.Series = Chart1.Series.ToList().ForEach( series => series.Enabled = false);`, but maybe that is the simplest option?

Comment: converting to a list is never simpler than just going through the elements.

Comment: LINQ stands for language integrated query.  Enabled = false is not a query.  What's wrong with a foreach?

Comment: Oops, yeah. You are correct -- I went back and looked through all of my previous threads and made sure I accepted and voted up relevant answers. A few people left responses that weren't helpful, though.

Comment: You could always try AsEnumerable() instead of ToList(), but I'm not sure that you actually gain anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `foreach` is preferred for what you're trying to do.  You're iterating over a sequence of elements and modifying the elements.  That's what `foreach` is for.

Linq is used to take one sequence of elements and generate a new sequence based on some criteria/transformation.  Not what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and one line :)

```
foreach (var series in Chart1.Series) { series.Enabled = false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

your first foreach loop is pretty clear and it works, so why need to replace it with LINQ, it wont be more clear or faster.

Otherwise I dont think it will be simpler than what you say above

```
Chart1.Series.ToList().ForEach( series => series.Enabled = false);
```

Comment: ToList() creates a copy of the data, correct? I believe your statement would have no effect on Chart1.Series. I'm changing it around just because I am trying to gradually introduce myself into more complex LINQ commands, but don't have a ton of time at work to research LINQ -- so I just take small, learning steps when I can.

Comment: Did you try it? copy of reference data will do the job for actual data too

Comment: In your first example, the variable series contains a copy of the reference to the series object. The same way the ToList() will create a new object but containing references to the same items

Comment: Interesting! That... explains a lot, actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As to the specific reason your Select didn't work, bear in mind that Select returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is an object that knows how to enumerate.  In other words, you have a reference to something that can enumerate, but that hasn't yet been enumerated.  So if you take this:

```
var series = Chart1.Series.Select( s => s.Enabled = false);
foreach (var s in series) {}
```

You'll get the effect you intended, because now you're enumerating the Series and therefore calling the Select delegate.  This is rather non-intuitive, of course, which is why Select is typically not used in this way (otherwise every time you enumerate, you'll have side effects and enumerating more than once would apply the side effects again.)